# Android failed to load open nfc add-on

Tags: android, nfc, open-nfc

I am following [these](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/) instructions to setup open nfc emulators on my windows 7 system. As per instruction #2 I have copied Android nfc add-on to my Android SDK add-ons. The as per instruction #3 I have launched AVD manager to create new AVD with Open NFC add-on as target.

But I do not see open nfc add-on in target list. In android SDK manager, upon sorting the packeges repository wise, i can see onpe NFC add-on icon is broken, indicating `"Addon failed to load: null". See attached screenshot.

[image: Android SDK manager screenshot]
[image: Installed components list start]
[image: Installed components list continue]
[image: Installed components list ends]

Please share if anybody has experienced and solved this issue.

Thanks
iuq

Comment: Unfortunately, your screenshot does not really provide sufficient information. Could you provide a list of all components that you have installed (select *Show: Installed*, and preferably *Sort by: API level*) in SDK manager)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland - I have updated the question with screenshots of installed components.

Comment: Installed components look good (particularly the required API 17 components seem to be installed). Do the folder permissions for the OpenNFC add-on match the permissions used for other add-on/platforms folders?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I found source.properties file missing. See my answer for details.

Comment: @iuq I've copied the add-ons to SDK folder, but I can't see the open-nfc in sdk manager. I do have source.properties in it.

Answer (score 6):

I looked into other addons and noticed **openNFC addon** didn't have `source.properties` file. I've just copied one from other addon and changed values of following properperties

```
Addon.NameDisplay=addon-2013-02-28_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.2  
Addon.NameId=OpenNFC_4.5.2  
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=17
```

It works fine now.

Thanks,
iuq

Comment: There is no `add-ons` folder in my `sdk` folder. So I created manually and then I pasted `addon-2013-02-28_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.2` into `sdk/add-ons`. after than I open `sdk` manager. same error I am also getting(whatever you faced). So I am planning fix this issue as per your answer but I don't have any sample `source.properties` file. where can I find that. can you suggest me.

Comment: @MichaelRoland cay check above comment.

Comment: This worked for the Google APIs level 8 that were marked obsolete in the SDK but manually installed fine except they were missing this file.